# How to score random numbers in a way the lower the number is, the more scores it gives?

Tags: algorithm, math

There is a function that gives random decimal numbers from -Inf to +Inf includes fractional numbers.

I need "to weight" every number and "to give" a score to every number - the lower the number, the more scores. Scores must be positive numbers.

For example, if the function gives -10 and 0.1 then -10 should be scored more than 0.1.
But in every step, the function gives only one number, and  I don't know how many numbers there will be.

I've puzzled over it for a long time and I can not find any solution :(

Comment: return exp(-x) ? Where x is your number.

Comment: @Ronald. Why exp? Why not just -x?

Comment: because -x will be very negative if you plug in a positive number. The score is defined to be positive

Comment: @MadPhysicist any sigmoid or similar function would work

Comment: @Ronald Oh gosh, I definitely have some math problems :) Thanks for your hint, It seems this is what I need!  Can you write it as an answer?

Comment: @Ronald. I missed the positive part. In that case, nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I prefer @Severin Pappadeux's answer over my initial suggestion because it is bounded, the easiest function that fulfils the requirements is exp(-x).
(I added this as an answer because the OP requested me to do so).

Comment: Bumped. I updated my answer as well with discussion about range limitations

Answer (score 3):

How about [Sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function?

In Python

```
def S(x):
    return 1.0/(1.0+math.exp(-x))

def weight(x):
    '''from 1 to 0'''
    return 1.0-S(x)
```

Thus, score would be growing function from 1.0 at -infinity to 0.0 at +Infinity

PS And you could stretch X axis by using some scaling parameter

```
k = 10.0
return 1.0/(1.0+math.exp(-k*x))
```

UPDATE

As @Ronald noted, we should invert our Sigmoid

UPDATE II

And if exponent is too fast growing function, you could use polynomial sigmoid

Along the lines

```
def PolyS(x):
    '''from -1 to 1'''
    return x/math.sqrt(1.0+x*x)

def weight(x):
    return 1.0 - 0.5*(1.0 + PolyS(x))
```

Again, X could be scaled

UPDATE III

Please note, that for typical 64bit double number max.value is about 1.7976931348623157*10<sup>308</sup>, therefore maximum exponent argument is
about 709.8 before you'll get Overflow. This will affect Ronald's answer (pure exponent) as well as mine exponential sigmoid. If you sample range is much bigger, you either scale input or use polynomial sigmoid. Polynomial sigmoid might be made even more robust by using hypothenuse function, which suppose prevent overflows,
underflows and such.

Code below, you could try it and see how it fits.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def PolyS(x, scale=1.0):
    s = scale*x
    return s/np.hypot(1.0, s)

def weight(x, scale=1.0):
    return 1.0 - 0.5*(1.0 + PolyS(x, scale))

# plot weight with scale=0.5
x = np.linspace(-10., 10.)
plt.plot(x, weight(x, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

Comment: as far as I've understood the question, the function should return higher scores for smaller input. Hence e.g. +1 at -infinity and 0 at +infinity strictly descending. I like the normalisation that avoids the infinity of exp(-x) (my suggestion as a comment) at -infinity. (1 - S(x) would do the trick)

Comment: @Ronald Thanks for notice, obviously we should revert sigmoid, answer corrected

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, thank you for your answer. Have I understood correctly, the difference between your answer and the exponential function is the speed of growing?

Comment: @RomanAndreev Difference is in the weight range, I prefer it to be bounded and go from 1 to 0 when X is going from -Infinity to +Infinity. My S(x) based function wrt grows speed has the same behavior as exponent, because it is based on exponent. PolyS(x) will have slower speed of growing, and you could check other sigmoids as well, maybe they fit your domain better. Please check my update as well for discussion about range